# Extracting columns within a range AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I've been trying to extract lines where a number in one columns falls within a particular range.

Lets say I have a file that looks as so:

```
chrom    prediction
chrom1    0.75
chrom2    0.5
chrom4    0.76
```

If I wanted to print lines where the prediction value was in the range from 0.75-0.8, my output would look as so:

```
chrom    prediction
chrom1    0.75
chrom2    0.76
```

I've tried this, but it failed. Where did I go wrong?

```
awk '$2 >= "0.7" && < "0.75" ' Coverage7_haploscores_removed.txt > range_07_075.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to test for `0.75-0.8` but wrote code to test for `0.7-0.75` and you forgot to specify what to test in the second part of your condition. Do this:

```
awk '$2 >= 0.75 && $2 <= 0.8'
```

Also note that you want a numeric comparison not a string comparison so lose the quotes.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I apologize for my mistake in the question.